# Extracting specific rows based on increasing or decreasing values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with two columns and a datetime index. When plotting a section of it, it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, data can go up (charging) or down (discharging) (sometimes remaining constant through these cycles) according to the SOC column.

The dataframe looks like the following:

```
                      SoC  Power
2021-09-25 16:40:00  0.76   2.18  
2021-09-25 16:40:10  0.76   2.14  
2021-09-25 16:40:20  0.77   2.18  
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.76   1.14
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14
```

I want to extract the first charging and discharging cycles. In this example, the expected output would be new dataframes as:

"Charging":

```
                      SoC  Power
2021-09-25 16:40:00  0.76   2.18  
2021-09-25 16:40:10  0.76   2.14  
2021-09-25 16:40:20  0.77   2.18
```

"Discharging"

```
                      SoC  Power
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.76   1.14
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14
```

My closest approach for extracting a charging session was the following:

```
max = df_3['SoC'].diff() < 0
idx = max.idxmax()
df = df.loc[df.index[0]:idx]
```

However, it only works when the data starts with a charging session (as all it does is stop whenever the values begin to decrease). I want a solution that works despite the initial data point and gives me the first charging cycle data points.

Comment: you should provide a minimal example of the data (and the expected output)

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a minimal working example.

Comment: can you share your expected output? the expected dates in output

Comment: I think looking for max/min probably isn't the right approach to find a cycle.  You should check the range, and identify a high/low threshold (say 95%/5%), and then use that to identify the start/end of charging cycles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, I just edited the post. Hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact expected output is unclear, but here is an approach to split each phase (charging, discharging) in a dictionary (2 statuses: charging/discharging, with a list of all phases per status):

```
s = np.sign(df['SoC'].diff())
s2 = s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill().bfill().map({1: 'charging', -1: 'discharging'})

from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for (status,_), d in s2.groupby([s2, s2.ne(s2.shift()).cumsum()]):
    out[status].append(d)
    
dict(out)
```

output:

```
{'charging': [2021-09-25 16:40:00    charging
  2021-09-25 16:40:10    charging
  2021-09-25 16:40:20    charging
  Name: SoC, dtype: object],
 'discharging': [2021-09-25 16:40:30    discharging
  2021-09-25 16:40:30    discharging
  2021-09-25 16:40:30    discharging
  Name: SoC, dtype: object]}
```

For a single item:

```
out['charging'][0]
```

output:

```
2021-09-25 16:40:00    charging
2021-09-25 16:40:10    charging
2021-09-25 16:40:20    charging
Name: SoC, dtype: object
```

##### as DataFrame:

```
s = np.sign(df['SoC'].diff())
df['status'] = (s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill().bfill()
                 .map({1: 'charging', -1: 'discharging'})
                )
df['phase']  = s2.ne(s2.shift()).cumsum()
```

output:

```
                      SoC  Power       status  phase
2021-09-25 16:40:00  0.76   2.18     charging      1
2021-09-25 16:40:10  0.76   2.14     charging      1
2021-09-25 16:40:20  0.77   2.18     charging      1
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.76   1.14  discharging      2
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14  discharging      2
2021-09-25 16:40:30  0.75   1.14  discharging      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how the data is, but I think that creating a window walking through the data is a good idea and which pandas has a functionality for it.

I explain:
The window starts small, it moves through the data and can potentially increase in size by checking if the pattern of increase or decrease is still there. In case of a change in pattern the window will be transformed to its original size and repeat the process until the end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).